# Linux Delete Files Batch Script

Tags: linux, bash, batch-file

I have a list of file names of files i need to delete.

Is there a way to write a batch file that i can specify Linux to delete these files with the given names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply call:

```
\rm -f $(<file.txt)
```

To remove all the files listed in a file called file.txt (1 per line of course).

Comment: How can i make sure these files are being removed?

Comment: Instead of `\rm -f` you can use `\rm -i` and that will show each and every file to you and ask for confirmation before removing.

Comment: @anubhava Can you please explain the command. What happens if the command is prepended with backslash? Won't this command fail for a very large file?

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi: Backslash before any command makes sure that your local alias are ignored as many people alias rm, cp, mv etc commands in their local .bashrc, .profile. If list of files to be deleted is huge in input huge then it is better to delete files in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Say you have a file "file":

```
foobar.txt
frob
media/music.m3u
```

Then you can pipe the contents to `xargs`, which will append the piped-in stuff line per line to the argument specified, and execute it:

`cat file | xargs rm`

Answer (score 2):

As a bash one liner

```
cat yourfile.txt |while read line; do rm ${line}; done
```

Comment: So i would need to add a bunch of these lines with the file names? And what do i name the batch file and how do i run it in terminal?

Comment: The principle is the same as presnel's I believe (xargs is pretty neat).  You said you have a list of files, create some file "yourfile.txt" with all the filenames listed, then run the command at a bash prompt.

Comment: Understood because i have about 30,000 files i need to delete haha.

Comment: I put my text file in the folder of the images.

i had it formatted with the image file names for example name.jpg going down line by line.

but when i ran it i get this.



`rm: cannot lstat `6td2h4mk.jpg': No such file or directory` for all of them specified to their file names

Comment: You might need to run fsck.  I've also had to put ${line} in quotes before... like:  do rm -i "${FILE}";

Comment: Try quotes, however it works as is on my system.  Are all your files in the same directory where you are running the command?

Comment: I am running it in an image folder using terminal i have a txt file with about 60k file names now including their extension on all single lines.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7334/discussion-between-mystycs-and-niall-byrne)